# Scroll function is executed even when conditions aren't met: React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new to React and coding in general so please bear with me.

I'm trying to only execute the function changeBackground when the location.pathname is equal to '/', but for some reason it executes on other pages like '/about' etc.

Please help.

```
 const location = useLocation();
 const [colorBackground, setColorBackground] = useState(false);
 
 useEffect(() => {
   if(location.pathname === '/') {
     const changeBackground = () => {
       if(window.scrollY >= 80) {
         setColorBackground(true);
       } else {
         setColorBackground(false);
       }
     }
   
     document.addEventListener('scroll', changeBackground);

   } else {
     setColorBackground(true);
   }
 }, [location.pathname])
```

Comment: It looks like you're adding an event listener but then never removing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a memory leak problem, when this component is mounted the `useEffect` is checking the `location.pathname` and adding an event listener to the document that executes the `changeBackground` function. This event is going to keep in the DOM as it has not been added by React mechanism so you are directly manipulating the DOM. Therefore you need to take care of cleaning up the listener when the pathname changes. You could modify your component as follows.

```
 const location = useLocation();
 const [colorBackground, setColorBackground] = useState(false);

 const changeBackground = () => {
       if(window.scrollY >= 80) {
         setColorBackground(true);
       } else {
         setColorBackground(false);
       }
 }
 
 useEffect(() => {
   if(location.pathname === '/') {
   
     document.addEventListener('scroll', changeBackground);

   } else {
     document.removeEventListener('scroll', changeBackground);
     setColorBackground(true);
   }

   return () => {
     document.removeEventListener('scroll', changeBackground);
   }
 }, [location.pathname])
```